# Is there a way to bake a Child Of constraint with proper subframe interpolation?

Tags: animation, rigging, export, constraints, unreal-engine

I'm exporting animations from Blender into Unreal, this requires them to be baked.
I have a set-up with a separate custom bone for the sword that has a Child Of constraint to the hand. Everything looks correct when played back before baking (using the Subframes option to check the interpolation between frames). However, when the animation is baked, everything remains correct on the exact frames, but everything in between (subframes) are completely wrong.

I understand this is because Child Of operates in World Space, correct? Is what I'm trying to do impossible without parenting the Sword bone to the hand?

[image]

Comment: Could you demonstrate exactly what you mean by wrong subframe interpolation?  On the baked animation?  You can inspect your subframes by scaling your frames in the time axis.  After baking with visual keyframes + clear constraints, subframes should be fine (it's before baking that they might be wacky with a child-of with changing influence.)

Comment: I'm turning on subframes in the playback options to inspect the baked animation (with visual keyframes + clear constraints too). Same result when scaling up the animation. If I'm understanding correctly, subframes are potentially infinite and are derived from the curves that depend on local axes so there's no way to achieve what I want. (A sword bone being a child of the root bone that is constrained with Child Of to the hand)

Comment: Like I said, subframes should be fine, so to get some help here, you're probably going to have to provide a file, with unbaked but ready-to-bake animation, and a particular subframe you want us to look at.

Comment: @Nathan I've just attached the file to my post where I recreated this issue with a minimal FK and IK set-ups. 
To confirm the issue: turn on subframes and playback an animation. Then bake the animation and do the same. You will see the sword bone detaching from the bone it's constrained to.

Comment: I believe that what you are tying to do is completely wrong. In game engines like Unreal, you are able to set parent dynamically, change visibility of the object or even create an instance of the object on the fly using code. These are the technics that you should use instead of trying to simulate the more convenient ways of achieving this task

Comment: That's what I'm doing in Unreal right now, actually, it's just that you end up doing this work twice and I was wondering if there's a way to make the animation looks exactly like it does in blender without additional hassle. For reference, the animations I have include complex motions like actually juggling the sword and such so I absolutely do need a sword bone. Because I set-up the child constraint in Unreal I now need to also dynamically unparent and reparent it dynamically during the animation as well.

Comment: But there's probably no other way since I'm not sure how it would work mathematically (I don't think there's enough data contained in the keyframes for any animation player to understand the child constraint implied because the movement is still based off of local axes). This was just to sanity check myself before I spend a lot of time on working this through in Unreal instead. Thanks for the input @Crantisz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I see what you're saying.  This isn't an issue with child-of specifically, but any constraint.

The issue is that when a bone is constrained, its transform is the multiplication of a bunch of different transforms, but once you bake and disable that constraint, that bone no longer has access to all of the information it would need to interpolate between keyframes the same way.

Let's imagine we have a monkey, child-of'd to the hand of a clock, making 1 rotation every four frames.  Here's what we'll see:

[image]

At position 1,2,3,4, the monkey is where it should be.  However, there's no keyframe for 4.5.  So the orientation at 4.5 is a blend halfway between 4 and 1.  That means that the monkey is no longer at the same distance from the center of the circle, because it's no longer rotating about the center of the circle.  Instead, it's translating between two positions at the same time that it's rotating about its own center.  And, importantly, *it no longer knows where the center of the circle is.*  Its keyframes do not depend on the circle in any way.  And keyframes alone are incapable of storing information like, "we're actually rotating about some other point."

What should we do?  If we're rendering 4 frames, this is fine; we're never going to show frame 4.5 anyways.  But what if we plan on rendering 8 frames?  Then we should bake 8 frames of information.  (We can do that by scaling the keyframes x2 about frame 0, baking, and then scaling back down to half, our original size, so that we have twice as many keyframes baked.  You will need to disable frame snapping to scale back down to half-frames.  Unfortunately, Blender doesn't directly support frame steps of less than 1 for baked actions.)

We can do that to create keyframes to any *sampled* subframe count we want.  Typically, video game artists are aiming at 30hz animation: 30 keyframes for every second.  If you don't mind the memory cost, you can sample at 60hz instead, or even 240hz.

If, for whatever reason, we need *infinite* interpolation, then we either have to use live constraints (or code the equivalent of constraints into whatever game engine we're using) or use real, non-constraint parenting to do it.  Real parenting, in this case, might be to create an empty, give it copy transforms from the hand of the clock, parent the monkey to it, and then bake the constraints for the empty.  That way, the empty has no interpolation problems, because it's rotating about the exact same origin as the thing it's copying, and the monkey is inheriting that transform.

But the realistic option here is just, if you need better interpolation, then bake more keyframes.